# Could not find relevant edges for attributes

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I get the following error:

> Could not resolve symbolic constant for constraint, because: Could not
>   find relevant edges for attributes: centerX and centerX.
>
> Use a symbolic
>   breakpoint at
>   NSLayoutConstraintFailedToFindDefaultResolvedValueForSymbolicConstant
>   to debug.

If I add a breakpoint at `NSLayoutConstraintFailedToFindDefaultResolvedValueForSymbolicConstant` it stops at this line:

`[self.customNavigationBar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor].active = YES;`

This line is called within the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller. `customNavigationBar` is a UIView loaded from a nib which already have been added as subview to `self.view`.

If I try to print out the anchors I am using everything seems ok:

```
(lldb) po self.customNavigationBar.widthAnchor
<NSLayoutDimension:0x17446cc80 "UIView:0x10115c160.width">

(lldb) po self.view.widthAnchor
<NSLayoutDimension:0x170667080 "UIView:0x1012ae550.width">
```

Comment: What is `customNavigationBar`? Is it a `UINavigationBar` added as a subview to `self.view`? Or is it a subclassed controller?

Comment: It is a UIView loaded from a nib, see edited question.

Comment: Just to narrow things down... If you comment-out that line, do you still get an error? If so, on a similar line? If so, can you get it to run without error if you don't set any constraints on `customNavigationBar`? (I know it won't be in the right place, but just debugging....)

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?  I'm just now running into this problem myself and am going to be digging into the reasons in the morning.  Thanks

Comment: No, but I also didn’t look further into it.

Answer (score 5):

This error comes from your choice of constructor for the `NSLayoutConstraint`.

You probably have something like this:

```swift
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: otherView.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true
```

But you should construct it like this:

```swift
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: otherView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 1)

constraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Why does the choice of initializer matter here? What's the difference between the two options?

Comment: The difference here is that the NSLayoutAnchor api (subtly) doesn't make any sense here. We're using `equalToSystemSpacingBelow` but there is no SystemSpacing for centers. Change that to `view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true` and the error will do away.

Comment: @alexkent - `multiplier` is not a valid argument for an `equalTo` constraint. It's either nothing or you can use `constant`.

Comment: @C6Silver you're right of course. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet but I think this answer helped me a lot... If you're right -- and it seems to -- then Apple let's you call APIs using never-legal constraints that it flags only at runtime. Grumble grumble +1 thanks